# JavFX FXML Loading Error (Nullpointerexception)

Tags: java, javafx, loading, fxml

Yeah i know this question has often been asked, i used the searching function but couldl'nt solve my problem with these answers, and now im tired to search at google or anywhere else.

My Problem: I try to load an FXML File into my Javacode:

```
public class Main extends Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    try {

        //Layout laden
        Pane pane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("layout/main_layout.fxml"));

        //Scene erstellen und initialisieren
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("css/main_layout.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        //Breite und Höhe der Stage setzen
        primaryStage.setWidth(1024);
        primaryStage.setHeight(768);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Untitled - jNotepad");

        primaryStage.show();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

My FXML file is in the package de.toxiclab.jNotepad.layout, that means realtive to the path in layout/main_layout.fxml, so the path has to be correct.

And then it prints me this ugly exception:

> > javafx.fxml.LoadException:  /J:/Eclipse%20Workspace/jNotepad/bin/de/toxiclab/jNotepad/layout/main_layout.fxml:19
>
> at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2617)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2595)    at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3230)     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3191)     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3164)     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3140)     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3120)     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3113)     at
>   de.toxiclab.jNotepad.Main.start(Main.java:32)     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$8.run(LauncherImpl.java:837)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$7.run(PlatformImpl.java:335)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:301)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:298)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6.run(PlatformImpl.java:298)
>     at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
>     at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)  at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$300(WinApplication.java:39)
>     at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$4$1.run(WinApplication.java:112)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   de.toxiclab.jNotepad.NotepadController.getStage(NotepadController.java:199)
>     at
>   de.toxiclab.jNotepad.NotepadController.(NotepadController.java:45)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
>     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:433)  at
>   sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(ReflectUtil.java:51)     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:932)
>     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:976)
>     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:216)
>     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:738)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2723)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)    ... 19 more

But i dont understand, why theres an damn Nullpointerexception, the PATH is 100% correct.

Comment: what is at NotepadController, line 199?

Comment: return ((Stage)this.textPane.getScene().getWindow());

Comment: If I  had to guess, it's trying to grab the window before the scene is completely shown, which is causing your null-pointer exception, you might have to add a `WindowEvent.WINDOW_SHOWN` handler to the stage in that point and then try to get the window once it's shown

Comment: And how can i do this ? Just modify the getStage method ?

Comment: I'll make an answer about it, one sec

Comment: Show the controller code.

Answer (score 2):

So after seeing the error seemingly centering around the controller class 'NotePadController' I believe the reason you are seeing this `NullPointerException` is due to the fact that the nodes haven't been attached to the scene yet. In light of this, you may want to try attaching a `WindowEvent.WINDOW_SHOWN` handler onto that point in the method.

for example:

you mentioned that line 199 was `return ((Stage)this.textPane.getScene().getWindow());`

perhaps, instead, it would be better to have a static `Window` variable (say called 'window' ) and say:

```
(Stage)this.addEventHandler(WindowEvent.WINDOW_SHOWN, new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(WindowEvent event) {
                window = ((Stage)this.textPane.getScene().getWindow());
            }
 });
```

or something along those lines.

It's also possible the main meat of the error is coming from somewhere else. Good luck! sometimes these types of problems can be a touch tricky.

Comment: the NPE is because at the point he accesses it the nodes have not yet been attached to a scene.

Comment: true, that's a better way of saying it, I'll update the answer.